# How to make gtsave do not ignore borderlines?

Tags: r, gt

I need to create a table in gt.
In my code which I run through output you can see dotted lines.

[image]
But in file saved using gtsave there are no such lines.
[image]

Why and to change it?
Lines where produced

```
tab_style(
style = cell_borders(
  sides = c("bottom"),
  color = "gray",
  weight = px(1.5),
  style = "dotted"
),
locations = cells_body(rows = c(3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21)))
```

And to save it:

```
gtsave(tab1, "tab1.png")
```